# installing maya 2019 ubuntu 18.04 blank pop up running ./setup

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I  am new in ubuntu any help will be really thanks full.
I want to install maya 2019 in my ubuntu 18.04 with this following version :
command :

```
lsb_release -a


No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

64-bit,

with reference from maya official web i just must type command `./setup`, I have face some problem before. such as installing this 
command :

```
sudo apt-get install libpng12-0
apt-cache policy libpng12-0

libpng12-0:
  Installed: 1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.2.54-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

and when i type `sudo su ./setup` the pop-up windows is shown but it's blank page doesn't show anything, and in the terminal shows this errors :

```
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Resource id:  0x3a0000a
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 5 (X_ShmCreatePixmap)
  Resource id:  0x3a00010
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a00011
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a00011
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a00011
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a00011
X Error: BadPixmap (invalid Pixmap parameter) 4
  Major opcode: 54 (X_FreePixmap)
  Resource id:  0x3a00011
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 2 (X_ShmDetach)
  Resource id:  0x3a00010
```

I have search what this error but doesn't understand what is this. Any suggestion or explenation is  really thanks full

Comment: If you're running 18.04 (bionic) why do 16.04 (xenial) sources appear in your `apt-cache policy` results?  *I would check & clean your sources.list\* files*

Comment: because before that i have seen some tutorial  and they explain if maya need some dependencies that support in linux 16.04 dist, thanks for clean my source

Comment: Okay - I see via https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libpng12-0  why (but it's a messy hack)

Comment: sure,sorry i am nor really know about that, I just follow a tutorial. and than face same problem, that's not installed libpng12-0. And that give me a command to install it. must i remove it?

Comment: You should provide the instructions you are following in your question:  I don't know maya (2019) & because of the warning "*Warning: This package is intended for the use in building debian-installer images only. Do not install it on a normal Ubuntu system.*" for that package I'm unwilling to advise sorry.  Be patient & someone else maybe able to help.

Comment: ok i got this command to fixed blank window sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 ./setup
but got error "rpm should not be used directly install rpm packages use alien" during installation